# Can an IOrderedEnumerable bindingsource be created from a DBSet?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I want to dynamically specify a number of columns to sort by.

My code is as follows

```
var dset = Context.People;
var QuickSearch = "a";                
var qry  = dset.Where( p => p.LastName.Contains(QuickSearch) );
 qry.Load();
 BindingSource bindingsource;
 bindingSource.DataSource = dset.Local.ToBindingList();
```

I want to use the  technique in the answer outlined 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549788/how-to-perform-multiple-linq-to-entities-orderings-dynamically)

Thus I should be able to do something like  ( simplified )

```
IQueryable<Person> qry = null;
qry = base.Context.People.OrderBy(x=>x.FirstName);  // this is OK
qry = qry.ThenBy(y=>y.LastName);   // This wont compile
```

However it doesn't compile.

[Update]
  Since ThenBy is an extension method for IOrderable My question becomes
  Can an IOrderedEnumerable bindingsource be created from a DBSet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it to be like this:

```
var qry = base.Context.People.OrderBy(x=>x.FirstName);  
qry = qry.ThenBy(...)
```

or

```
IOrderedQueryable<Person> qry = null;
qry = base.Context.People.OrderBy(x=>x.FirstName);  
qry = qry.ThenBy(y=>y.LastName);
```

The reason is that you are declaring qry as `IQueryable`, when `ThenBy` is an extension method for `IOrderedQueryable` (which is what `OrderBy` returns)

Comment: When I do that I get an error `
cannot convert type system.linq.IOrderedQueriable<DomainClasses.Person> to target type system.linq.IOrderedEnumerable<DomainClasses.Person>  on the line `qry=base.Context.People.OrderBy(x=>x.FirstName)`

Comment: Try defining `qry` as IOrderedQueryable<Person> or using the first approcah